# 電話する and 電話をかける

Tags: word-choice, meaning

From what I have seen, they are both used to say " to call someone" by phone, but I was wondering if there was a difference between the two. Is one more formal?  Is there a nuance in meaning? Are there situations where one could not be used while the other could? 
Thanks.

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/776/to-make-a-telephone-call

Comment: Are we sure we want to close this as a duplicate?  Is this question adequately addressed by the answers on the other?

Comment: I think the answer over there is good enough. That's exactly  (or far better than) what I would write here.